# How to perform lookup based on column header name?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

Hope someone can assist with constructing the following query.

**CodeTypes**

```
Code |  ID  | Type
---------------------
ABC  | 1234 | 'Type1'
ABC  | 1234 | 'Type2'
CDE  | 2345 | 'Type1'
CDE  | 2345 | 'Type3'
EFG  | 3456 | 'Type2'
```

**TypeValues**

```
Code |  ID  |  Type1  |  Type2  |  Type3
----------------------------------------
ABC  | 1234 | ';kjap' | ')&jaa' | '123ja' 
CDE  | 2345 |   NULL  | '$@#$a' | 'asdfa'
EFG  | 3456 | '&*(01' | 'jmblk' |   NULL
```

I would like to be able to construct the trailing column 'TypeValue' which is essentially a lookup based on `Code` & `ID` within the `TypeValues` table for a particular `Type`.

```
Code |  ID  |  Type   |  TypeValue
----------------------------------
ABC  | 1234 | 'Type1' |  ';kjap' 
ABC  | 1234 | 'Type2' |  ')&jaa'
CDE  | 2345 | 'Type1' |   NULL
CDE  | 2345 | 'Type3' |  'asdfa'
EFG  | 3456 | 'Type2' |  'jmblk'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CASE` to choose which column to use. For example:

```
select
  t.*,
  case when t.type = 'Type1' then v.type1
       when t.type = 'Type2' then v.type2
       when t.type = 'Type3' then v.type3
  end as typevalue
from codetypes t
join typevalues v on v.code = t.code and v.id = t.id
```

**EDIT per HABO's comment**:

The query can be simplified further to:

```
select
  t.*,
  case t.type when 'Type1' then v.type1
              when 'Type2' then v.type2
              when 'Type3' then v.type3
  end as typevalue
from codetypes t
join typevalues v on v.code = t.code and v.id = t.id
```

Comment: Or use a [_simple_ CASE expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), rather than _searched_, since it is testing one expression (`t.type`) against multiple values: `case t.type when 'Type1' then v.type1 when 'Type2' then v.type2 when 'Type3' then v.type3 end`.

Answer (score 2):

First of all: If you can change the design, you should do this. Whenever you feel the need to *name-number* columns (Type1, Type2...) this is bad design.

Looking for a fully generic approach you can give this a try:

```
DECLARE @CodeTypes TABLE(Code VARCHAR(100),ID INT,[Type] VARCHAR(100));
DECLARE @TypeValues TABLE(Code VARCHAR(100),ID INT,Type1 VARCHAR(100),Type2 VARCHAR(100),Type3 VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @CodeTypes(Code,ID,[Type]) VALUES
 ('ABC',1234,'Type1')
,('ABC',1234,'Type2')
,('CDE',2345,'Type1')
,('CDE',2345,'Type3')
,('EFG',3456,'Type2');

INSERT INTO @TypeValues(Code,ID,Type1,Type2,Type3) VALUES
 ('ABC',1234,';kjap',')&jaa','123ja') 
,('CDE',2345,  NULL ,'$@#$a','asdfa')
,('EFG',3456,'&*(01','jmblk',  NULL );
```

--The query

```
SELECT ct.Code
      ,ct.ID,ct.[Type]
      ,(SELECT tv.* FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE)
       .value('(*[local-name()=sql:column("Type")]/text())[1]','varchar(100)') TypeValue  
FROM @CodeTypes ct
INNER JOIN @TypeValues tv ON ct.ID=tv.ID
                         AND ct.Code=tv.Code;
```

The idea in short:

- We use a simple JOIN to get both tables together.
- The magic is XML's ability to grab a column by its name.
- We query *one single row* of `tv` for each row of the resultset.
- We create a XML for the row an pick one value by a `local-name()` predicate.

Hint: This will not be fast, but - if you ever decide to add a `Type4` you will not have to rewrite existing queries...

Comment: I agree with you that -- though not fast -- this solution can be flexible.